# Increment ecx in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to increment a number so that the code will increment forever, but it stays zero.

Here is my code:

```
section .data
FORMAT: db '%c', 0
FORMATDBG: db '%d', 10, 0
EQUAL: db "is equal", 10, 0
repeat:
    push  ecx  ; just to print
    push  FORMATDBG ; just to print
    call  printf ; just to print
    add esp, 8 ; add the spaces
    inc ecx ; increment ecx
    cmp ecx, 0 ; compare ecx to zero
    ja repeat ; if not equal to zero loop again
```

Comment: Um, you're zeroing `ecx` at each iteration. So it's never gonna change...

Comment: i removed the xor, and now it returns some negative value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
repeat:
    xor ecx, ecx
    push  ecx  ; just to print
    push  FORMATDBG ; just to print
    call  printf ; just to print
    add esp, 8 ; add the spaces
    inc ecx ; increment ecx
    cmp ecx, 0 ; compare ecx to zero
    ja repeat ; if not equal to zero loop again
```

`xor ecx, ecx` sets `ecx` to zero. I'm not sure if you know this. You probably do not want it to happen on each iteration. Furthermore your loop condition `ja repeat` currently causes a loop only if `ecx > 0` which is probably not what you wanted (or is it?).

One last thing, `printf` probably trashes `ecx` (I am assuming `cdecl` or `stdcall`). Read up on call conventions (not sure what compiler/OS you are on) and see which registers are guaranteed to be preserved in function calls.

In terms of your code, you probably wanted something closer to this:

```
    xor ebx, ebx

repeat:
    push  ebx  ; just to print
    push  FORMATDBG ; just to print
    call  printf ; just to print
    add esp, 8 ; add the spaces
    inc ebx ; increment ecx
    cmp ebx, 0 ; compare ecx to zero
    ja repeat ; if not equal to zero loop again
```

This will not cause an infinite loop though. When `ebx` reaches its maximum value, its value will wrap around back to 0 which will cause the loop condition (`ebx>0`) to evaluate to false and your loop to be exited.

Comment: Sorry, i reoved the xor and now i get the -1074208095 value

Comment: @demonofnight: Did you try changing `ecx` to `ebx`?

Comment: i'm using ebx to store some data.

Comment: @demonofnight: Then use `esi` or `edi`. Did you check the call convention for your compiler/OS? If you can't use one of those two, then save and restore the register that is going to be crashed by the call by pushing it before and popping it after.